# Get the actual position of bone (head and tail) even when armature is rotated

Tags: python, armature, coordinates

I would like to know if it is possible to get the real coordinates of a bone's head and tail when the armature is rotated.
I already got something working with translations of armature but can't figure out how to do it when a rotation is applied.

To demonstrate what I want I created two cubes that will be moved to the bone's head and tail.
Here is the code :

```py
import bpy
armature = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bname = 'bone_2'
bone = armature.pose.bones[bname]

tail = bone.tail + armature.location
head = bone.head + armature.location


bpy.data.objects['head'].location = head
bpy.data.objects['tail'].location = tail
```

And here is the result without rotation and with rotation:

[image: Bone without rotation]
[image: Bone with rotation]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use matrix instead of position:

```
import bpy
armature = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bname = 'bone_2'
bone = armature.pose.bones[bname]

tail = armature.matrix_world @ bone.tail 
head = armature.matrix_world @ bone.head 


bpy.data.objects['head'].location = head
bpy.data.objects['tail'].location = tail
```